# How to generate a fixture list in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate a fixture list for a football league. I have managed to generate the actual fixture list without any issues but am now trying to generate a "week" for which the game to be played in. This only needs to be "1 to n", no other date information, just a week number.

The table I have created in MySQL is as follows:

```
Home     Away GameID WeekID
Team 2  Team 1  1      0
Team 3  Team 1  2      0
Team 3  Team 2  3      0
Team 4  Team 1  4      0
Team 4  Team 2  5      0  
Team 4  Team 3  6      0
Team 1  Team 2  7      0
Team 1  Team 3  8      0
Team 2  Team 3  9      0
Team 1  Team 4  10     0
Team 2  Team 4  11     0
Team 3  Team 4  12     0
```

Each team has to play home and away, hence the duplication in some games. However what I need to do as mentioned before is assign a week number to the game and a team can only play once a week.

What I'm trying to create is:

```
Home     Away GameID WeekID
Team 2  Team 1  1      1
Team 3  Team 1  2      2
Team 3  Team 2  3      3
Team 4  Team 1  4      4
Team 4  Team 2  5      5 
Team 4  Team 3  6      6
Team 1  Team 2  7      6
Team 1  Team 3  8      5
Team 2  Team 3  9      4
Team 1  Team 4  10     3
Team 2  Team 4  11     2
Team 3  Team 4  12     1
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for?

Comment: me neither ;) pls describe your problem in more detail and give your table structure

Comment: Hi, sorry, I know it isn't the clearest explanation ever. What I am after is giving each game a weekID element, so i know when the game is scheduled to play.  

Each team needs to play twice, once home and away which is generated and the output displayed in the main post.

Therefore, I need to create an algorithm to assign a weekID to a game and then a team also only plays once a week.

Structure is     (homeTeam varchar(30), awayTeam varchar(30), gameID int(2), weekID int(2) )

Comment: added an extra table to the main post to try and make it a little clearer

Comment: So what you mean to say is that each team must play one game against all other teams 'at home'. This, by definition, includes that all teams will play one game against all other teams as the 'visiting' team. Is this correct? And this also stipulates that each team will only play one game per week?

Comment: Hi Sammitch,

Exactly, they need to play one home game and one away game against every team but they can only play once a week.

Comment: The pseudo code I've been thinking about is:

If array does not contain home/away,
set week and add home/away to array,
else increment to next fixture, 
if no more teams, empty array and increment week.

But have no idea how to go about that.

Comment: So far I've got code that works perfectly for 4 or 8 teams, but not so much for any other number of teams. :I This is a very interesting problem, though.

Comment: I think SQL is not the best idea to solve problems like this. In my opinion that should be easier in PHP.

Comment: Hi Kamil, that might be the way to go, either way as long as the result gets to the MySQL database, I'm not entirely bothered where it comes from.

Comment: Think I'm at a situation close to Sammitch, works fine for 4 or 8 but anything else, it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution *works*, but I don't think it fills the schedule as efficiently as is possible for numbers of teams that are not powers of two. Also the efficiency of the code is n^2 [possibly n^3?] for all cases, so I hope you don't need to schedule more than a few hundred teams at once. :P

```
<?php
$teams = $_GET['t'];
$games = array();   //2D array tracking which week teams will be playing
$weeks = array();   //2D array tracking which teams are playing in a given week

// initialize
for( $i=0; $i<$teams; $i++ ) {
    $games[$i] = array();
    for( $j=0; $j<$teams; $j++ ) {
        if( $i == $j ) { $games[$i][$j] = -1; } //you can't play with yourself ;D
        else { $games[$i][$j] = NULL; }
    }
}

// do the work
for( $w=1, $noblanks=false; !$noblanks; $w++) {
    if( !isset($weeks[$w]) ) { $weeks[$w] = array(); }
    $noblanks = true;   //begin assuming there are no blank spots in the matrix
    for( $i=0; $i<$teams; $i++ ) {
        for( $j=0; $j<$teams; $j++ ) {
            if( $i == $j ) { continue; }    //you can't play with yourself ;D
            if( is_null($games[$i][$j]) ) {
                if( !isset($weeks[$w][$i]) && !isset($weeks[$w][$j]) ) {
                    $games[$i][$j] = $w;    //game between team i and j in week w
                    $weeks[$w][$i] = true;  //mark that team i has game in week w
                    $weeks[$w][$j] = true;  //mark that team j has game in week w
                } else { $noblanks = false; } //this cell is blank, and will be left blank.
            }
        }
    }
}

// display
echo '<pre>';
foreach($games as $row) {
    foreach($row as $col) {
        printf('%4d', is_null($col) ? -2 : $col);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
printf("%d teams in %d weeks\n", $teams, count($weeks));
echo '</pre>';
```

Sample output:

```
  -1   1   2   3
   4  -1   3   2
   5   6  -1   1
   6   5   4  -1
4 teams in 6 weeks

  -1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   7  -1   3   2   5   4   8
   8   6  -1   1   7   9   4
   9  10   5  -1   6   7  11
  10   9  11   8  -1   1   2
  11  12  10  13   3  -1  14
  12  13  15  16  17  18  -1
7 teams in 18 weeks
```

### Edit

I've figured out a method that's more 'week-efficient' for all cases except where the number of teams is a power of two. Essentially the number of weeks require becomes `2 * number_of_teams`.

With my '[pen-and-paper](https://twitter.com/Sammitch/status/263405415889526785)' methods I noticed that striping numbers diagonally across the matrix is pretty much ideal, and on my walk home I thought up a method where you can just feed in 2 team IDs, and a count of teams and it will give you back the week that that game should take place.

```
<?php

function getweek($home, $away, $num_teams) {
    if($home == $away) { return -1; }
    $week = $home+$away-2;
    if( $week > ($num_teams) ) {
        $week = $week-$num_teams;
    }
    if( $home>$away ) {
        $week += $num_teams;
    }
    return $week;
}

$teams = $_GET['t'];
$games = array();   //2D array tracking which week teams will be playing

// do the work
for( $i=1; $i<=$teams; $i++ ) {
    $games[$i] = array();
    for( $j=1; $j<=$teams; $j++ ) {
        $games[$i][$j] = getweek($i, $j, $teams);
    }
}

// display
echo '<pre>';
$max=0;
foreach($games as $row) {
    foreach($row as $col) {
        printf('%4d', is_null($col) ? -2 : $col);
        if( $col > $max ) { $max=$col; }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
printf("%d teams in %d weeks, %.2f weeks per team\n", $teams, $max, $max/$teams);
echo '</pre>';
```

Example Output:

```
  -1   1   2   3
   5  -1   3   4
   6   7  -1   1
   7   8   5  -1
4 teams in 8 weeks, 2.00 weeks per team

  -1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   8  -1   3   4   5   6   7
   9  10  -1   5   6   7   1
  10  11  12  -1   7   1   2
  11  12  13  14  -1   2   3
  12  13  14   8   9  -1   4
  13  14   8   9  10  11  -1
7 teams in 14 weeks, 2.00 weeks per team
```

### Edit (Apr 2013)

I have modified the `getWeek()` function to work for any number of teams. See the new function below. Jovan

```
function getWeek($home, $away, $num_teams) {
    if($home == $away){
        return -1;
    }
    $week = $home+$away-2;
    if($week >= $num_teams){
        $week = $week-$num_teams+1;
    }
    if($home>$away){
        $week += $num_teams-1;
    }

    return $week;
}
```

Comment: +1 for sharing code and "you can't play with yourself" comment :)

Comment: That is fantastic code Sammitch, the only thing left now is to iron out the errors I keep getting.

    `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/user/public_html/league/admin/fixtures.php on line 89`

which points to:

    `$games[$i][$j] = getweek($i, $j, $teams);`

but then if I increase the memory it then gets stuck at:

`$week = $home+$away-2;` with the error `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 889978880) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /home/user/public_html/league/admin/fixtures.php on line 53`

Comment: bit more information, worked out the getWeek function is being called a ridiculous amount of times, i stopped the script on the 212285 iteraction

Comment: solved it, was the way I was creating the teams array and using it other then that the code works :D

Comment: Great code, helped me greatly for my fantasy sports application. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the second version of the code doesn't work - for example, for 4 teams there should be 6 rounds, not 8 rounds.

Comment: @jovan as I noted, the first bit of code above the edit works best for a number of teams that is a power of two, the second bit below the edit works best the rest of the time.

Comment: @Sammitch I see. I have tweaked the `getWeek()` function to work with any number of teams - I've taken the liberty of editing it into your answer. Of course, for odd numbers of teams, I'd add a '0' team as one team will be left hanging otherwise.